# RequestFactory Interface Validation issue

Tags: android, gwt, requestfactory, annotation-processing

I'm using RequestFactory in an Android Connected AppEngine project with a shared folder. The Eclipse AnnotationProcessor (that does the interface validation) works fine for the AppEngine project, but does not generate the MyRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder.java class for the Android project. It seems it does not do anything when I build the project. My project properties are like described in http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation.

Now my question: how can I obtain any information why the Interface Validation is not working? There is nothing in my logs or under "Problems".

Comment: I could at least generate the MyRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder.java file now by adding a parameter client => true under properties>Java Compiler>Annotation processor. However I'm still getting a runtime exception "The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the bla.bla.client.MyRequestFactory RequestFactory type" when trying to create a requestfactory instance, so eventually the issue is not fully solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - both projects were set up as per the link you provided.

I fixed it by changing the compiler version of BOTH the app engine and the Android project to 1.6.

The app engine was 1.4 when I imported it and I changed it to 1.6 (even though the workspace is set to 1.6). It didn't start working until I changed the compiler version of the Android project though. It was automatically set to 1.5.

Good luck